# Is intel core i3 compatible with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, 64-bit, amd-processor

I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 in my laptop. I have found that Ubuntu 18.04 requires:

> Choose this if you have a computer based on the AMD64 or EM64T architecture (e.g., Athlon64, Opteron, EM64T Xeon, Core 2). Choose this if you are at all unsure.

I have 64bit o.s X64 based  Intel core i3 processor.

Is Ubuntu 18.04 compatible with my laptop?

Comment: *amd64* is what modern intel & AMD x86_64 processors use. Intel tried to create a market for IA64 (intel's 64-bit architecture) but it failed in the marketplace, as *amd64* was x86 compatible and would run 32-bit and older code where as IA64 would not. IA64 was thus abandoned even by intel, AMD and intel make *amd64* processors.

Comment: Yes, but start up a live session and you will see for yourself.

Comment: Also note:  There was no Ubuntu release in 2018-February (18.02 with the *yy.mm* format of releases used by Ubuntu and *flavors*), so that was either a *typo* or not a Ubuntu image at all, so be careful of any 18.02 release (it's fake)

Comment: ^^This, and also there is not really much reason to prefer 18.04 over 20.04.